# How to post mulitple check box value using ajax jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

Hello I am creating the multiple check box and one button for delete. This delete button use for the delete multiple check box value.I try this but when I use fire bug console that time given error is www.xyz.com/undefined 
my code is below

message.blade.php

```
<button type="submit" class="delete-msg btn btn-md btn-round btn-green pull-right hug-me-tight worldoo-btn-xs">Delete</button>
          </p>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          @foreach ($messages as $message)
          <li class="{{ $message == $messages[0] ? "active" : ""}}"> 
          <a class="message-sender-tab" data-sender-id="{{$message->sender_id}}" href="#v-home" data-toggle="tab">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_box" data-id="check_box" value="{{$message->sender_id}}" />
            <span class="photo"> <img alt="" class="img-circle" src="{{$message->sender->avatar->image->url()}}"></span> 
            <span class="subject"> <span class="from">{{$message->sender->username}}</span> </span> 
            <span class="message">{{$message->message}}</span> 
            <span class="time">{{$message->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</span> 
            </a> 
          </li>
          @endforeach
```

messenger.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.delete-msg').click(function(){
    $.post("/api/v1/messages/delete/"+ $(this).data('check_box'), function(data){ 
    alert("Message delete!");
});  });});
```

routes.php

```
Route::post("/messages/delete/{sender_id}",array("uses" => "MessagesController@deleteMessages"),function($sender_id){
  return $sender_id;   });
```

controller

```
public function deleteMessages($sender_id)
{
    $user = Auth::user()->user();
    $current_user_id = $user->id;
    $messages  = Message::whereRaw('sender_id = ? and recipient_id = ?', array($sender_id, $current_user_id))->delete();
    if (Request::wantsJson())
    {
        return Response::json($messages->toJson());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i dont see where you are getting the data from the check box. Why do dont u get them, lets say for example like so:

```
// if u have a form with id
$(".delete-msg").click(function() {
    $("input", "#formID").attr("checkboxName");
});

// if u dont have a form, then you can get an array of all input name
$(".delete-msg").click(function() {
    $("input").attr("checkboxName");
});
```

So you can assign it to a variable. Example

```
Var checkName = $("input").attr("checkboxName");
```

Answer (score 0):

The element that has a CSS class of `delete-msg` is a button tag and has no `data` attributes set. Therefore, when you call

```
$(this).data('check_box')
```

it does not exist.

You should select all checkbox elements on button click.